# Converting csv format column to comma separated list using bash

Tags: bash, gcloud

I need to convert a column which is in CSV format to a comma-separated list so that I can use a `for` loop on the list and use each parameter.

Here what I have tried:

```
$ gcloud dns managed-zones list --format='csv(name)' --project 'sandbox-001'
```

Output:

```
name
dns1
dns2
dns3
dns4
```

I need such result: "dns1,dns2,dns3,dns4" so that I can use a `for` loop:

```
x="dns1, dns2, dns3, dns4"
for i in $x:
   print $i
done
```

The `paste` command returns me the last line:

```
$ gcloud dns managed-zones list --format='csv(name)' --project 'sandbox-001' |paste -sd,

,dns4
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is apparently that the output has DOS line feeds. See [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) for a broader discussion, but for the immediate solution, try

```
tr -s '\015\012' , <file | sed 's/^[,]*,//;s/,$/\n/'
```

The arguments to `for` should just be a list of tokens anyway, no commas between them. However, a better solution altogether is to use `while read` instead. See also [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

```
gcloud dns managed-zones list --format='csv(name)' \
    --project 'sandbox-001' |
tr -d '\015' |
tail -n +2 |  # skip header line
while read -r i; do
    echo "$i"  # notice also quoting
done
```

I don't have access to `gcloud` but its manual page mentions several other formats which might be more suitable for your needs, though. See if the `json` or `list` format might be easier to manipulate. (CSV with a single column is not really CSV anyway, just a text file.)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. how can remove "name" which is in the first line of output?

Comment: The `sed` solution already does that. I'll update the `while` loop similarly.

Comment: nice, thanks. tail -n +2 worked .

Answer (score 0):

Create an array:

```
arr=( $(gcloud dns managed-zones list --format='csv(name)' --project 'sandbox-001') )
```

Than `printf` it like so:

```
printf -v var '%s,' "${arr[@]:1}"
```

This will create variable `$var` with value 'dns1,dns2,dns3,' `echo` it like this to drop last comma:

```
echo "${var%,}"
```